# Ungrounded Tower - Lightning Damage

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, structural-engineering

I have an 80 ft metal tower, that is cemented into a dirt ground, that houses two antennas to send and receive Wifi. The tower's power source is not a home. It has a dedicated line, that runs directly to it's own power meter. The tower is about 300 feet from a concrete home. The internet company says, that since the tower is buried in dirt, it is "already naturally grounded". I have other people who are saying it is extremely dangerous to not have it properly grounded with a copper rod. What are the potential dangers if lightening were to strike the tower?

Comment: An ungrounded tower seems like a very bad idea (and probably violates building regulations). Removing the grounding won't stop the tower being struck by lightening and will probably lead to more damage of the equipment. If the equipment was damaged by lightning previously the grounding may have not been installed properly.

Comment: A water pump as a power source makes no sense.  Antennas "used for internet" doesn't specify anything useful.  A real diagram would be useful instead of all this hand waving.  Then there is the wall of text.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the ground was the problem. It sounds like the ground was a bad one.

Comment: Since this question has just been edited - it seems to have lost a lot of the information about damage and has become a hypothetical problem. Is this what the OP asked or intended. As evidence of this just look at the other comments....

Comment: @SolarMike If you look at the edit history it was OP who removed most of the info.  The most recent edit was a small one.

Comment: @JMac So where do I find the edit history or is that something I don't have access to?

Comment: @SolarMike The light blue part where it says "Edited x long ago" is actually a link to the edit history.

Comment: @JMac thanks for the heads up, I had just thought that was the info when it was edited - not realised it was also a link, learn something new every day.

Comment: @Janelle I woud investigate the point by hassey - that the earth is a bad one - is the ground dry ? what type of soil etc any idea what other towers do in the area?